# Making custom class wrapper behave as pandas dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, class, pandas, dataframe

My Python class contains a Pandas dataframe object. My class is essentially a wrapper of the dataframe.

Is there now a way I can make the custom wrapper behave as a dataframe in terms of indexing.

E.g., can I achieve this:

```
myc = myclass(data=pandas_dataframe)
myc.loc[4,1]
myc.iloc[4,1]
```

and so on?

Is this a simple implementation of `__getitem__`? I am not sure how "loc" and "iloc", etc., are passed on...